# Boolean logic, negation of an OR

Tags: boolean, logic

I have the following logic:

```
if(!(A || B)) {}
```

How can this be simplified and how can this simplification be visualized?

```
A | B
-----
0   0
0   1  -
1   0   |- this is A OR B
1   1  -

A | B
-----
0   0  - This is !(A OR B) ?
0   1  
1   0  
1   1
```

Comment: `!A && !B` should be the equivalent of `!(A || B)`

Comment: [demorgans law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Try it with English: *`!(A || B)` = neither A nor B* is equivalent to *not A and also not B*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplification  `!(A || B) <=> !A && !B` (which is one of
De Morgan's laws, as noted by @JamesChoi) is best visualised
by observing that the truth value that accrues to the major
truth-functor in each expression is the same for all possible
distributions of truth values to the variables:

```
A  |  B  | !(A || B)  | !A && !B
---|-----|------------|----------
T  |  T  | F(T  T T)  | FT  F FT     
T  |  F  | F(T  T F)  | FT  F TF
F  |  T  | F(F  T T)  | TF  F FT
F  |  F  | T(F  F F)  | TF  T TF
---------------------------------
           ^                ^
```

This shows that the expressions are truth-functionally equivalent. It is an
application of the [truth-table method of propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

The truth table for `&&`  is:

```
A  |  B  | A && B
---|-----|-------
T  |  T  | T  T T     
T  |  F  | T  F F
F  |  T  | F  F T
F  |  F  | F  F F
```

and the truth-table for `||` (inclusive-or) is:

```
A  |  B  | A || B
---|-----|-------
T  |  T  | T  T T     
T  |  F  | T  T F
F  |  T  | F  T T
F  |  F  | F  F F
```

The truth-table for `!` must be self-evident.